# Is there a way to pass an object parameter as a reference to a WPF Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I am struggling to get a user control to accept a property from my Data Context object. I don't want to pass just the value; but the instance of the property because I would like to have converters operate on the attributes of the property.

I am very new to the WPF space, I've read many articles and none of them don't address this issue.  The reason I'm trying to do this is because I have a calculations class that has many properties that need to be displayed and I don't really want to create a user control for each property or have 2,000 lines of repetitious XAML.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Example Class

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    [MyAttribute("someValue")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

View Model

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private _myClass;
    public MyClass MyClass1
    {
        get => _myClass;
        set
        {
            if(_myClass != value)
            {
                _myClass = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Parent XAML

```xml
<UserControl DataContext="MyViewModel">
    <Grid>
        <!-- this is where I'm struggling, I think -->
        <uc:MyConsumerControl ObjectProp="{Binding Path=MyClass1.Foo}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

User Control

XAML

```xml
<UserControl DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ObjectProp}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ObjectProp, Converter={StaticResource MyAttrConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C#

```cs
public class MyConsumer : UserControl
{
    public MyConsumer { InitializeComponent(); }
    
    public object ObjectProp
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(ObjDepProp);
        set => SetValue(ObjDepProp, value);
    }
       
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjDepProp = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ObjectProp), 
            typeof(object), typeof(MyConsumer));
}
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but `DataContext="MyViewModel"` will only pass the string `"MyViewModel"` to the DataContext, not an instance of the class MyViewModel. You probably wanted to write `<UserControl.DataContext><local:MyViewModel/></UserControl.DataContext>`

Comment: However, setting `DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}` in MyConsumerControl 's XAML will break everything. It effectively prevents that `ObjectProp="{Binding Path=MyClass1.Foo}"` works.

Comment: Also be aware that there is a naming convention for the identifier field of a dependency property. For a property named `ObjectProp`, it must be named `ObjectPropProperty`.

Comment: Hi Clemens, thanks for responding.  I'm the goal is to get my user control to "see" the property as a property, so the control can handle all of the things that one may do with a property (e.g. get/set the value and pass it into a converter to process attributes). I'll get to work with your suggestions!

Comment: "*to see the property as a property*" does not make much sense. Get/set is surely something that could also be done with a field. And what's passed to a converter is the *value* of the source property of the Binding. Do you understand the issues I have listed in my previous comments?

Comment: HI Clemens, yes I understand. Perhaps my approach is very wrong... I have a class with a pile of properties and I would like to use a XAML template to display them. So to do this, I was trying to get a reference to the property and not to the property's value.  Perhaps I need to look at using the class's property collection as some type of iterative collection and use a proper data template.

Comment: Not sure what that is supposed to mean. Have you seen the answer? It should at least address all the technical issues.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is a naming convention for identifier fields of dependency properties:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjectPropProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ObjectProp), typeof(object), typeof(MyConsumer));

public object ObjectProp
{
    get => GetValue(ObjectPropProperty);
    set => SetValue(ObjectPropProperty, value);
}
```

Second, a UserControl that exposes bindable properties must never set its own DataContext, so this is wrong:

```
<UserControl DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}>
```

The XAML should look like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ObjectProp,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ObjectProp,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, />
                          Converter={StaticResource MyAttrConverter}}"
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Finally, this is also wrong, because it only assigns a string to the DataContext:

```
<UserControl DataContext="MyViewModel">
```

It could probably look like shown below - although that would again explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl, but perhaps one that could be considered a top-level view element like a Window or Page.

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <uc:MyConsumerControl ObjectProp={Binding Path=MyClass1.Foo}
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Clemens, thanks for all of your help.  I was able to solve my problems programmatically; there doesn't seem to be a XAML way to do what I needed to do.